# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user in xampp Local Host

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, localhost

Hi I am trying to import my db dump of wordpress site in local system by cmd comman line  using xammp server

command line

```
mysql -u proxsa1 -p **********< proxsa1.sql
```

it diverting me on below step

Next Step :

```
F:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u proxsa1 -p ********< proxsa1.sql
Enter password:
```

After submitting  the same password  of DB i am getting this error any idea how to fix

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'proxsa1'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
'#o' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'79I' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any solutions step by step

Answer (score 0):

The `-p` and password shouldn't have space(s) in between and should have space between password and `<`. Hence, you code should be written like :

```
mysql -u proxsa1 -p********** dbname < proxsa1.sql
```

e.g.

```
mysql -u user -pPASSWORD dbname < file.sql
```

**Edit:**

If you're importing to a different location, the command line should be something like this:

```
mysql.exe -h host/ip_address -P port(optional) -u user -pPASSWORD dbname < file.sql
```

1. `-h` is the host or ip address of the external MySQL service location.
2. `-P`(port) is only used when the MySQL service port is different than the default (usually `3306`). My usual command line looks like this:

```
mysql.exe -h mydb.com -P 3388 -u user -pPASSWORD dbname < file.sql
```

OR

```
mysql.exe -h 192.168.1.1 -P 3388 -u user -pPASSWORD dbname < file.sql
```

Comment: Not Solving issue it again giving same error

Comment: oh wait, you must specify database name as well.. see my edit

Comment: DB_NAME', 'proxsa1'
'DB_USER', 'proxsa1'
DB_PASSWORD', 'xyz'
DB_HOST', 'localhost

Comment: i was able to import the data without commd directly through phpmyadmin  but when i am running  the site on local it showing me error " Error establishing a database connection"  so i am again trying to upload the DB by command line and when doing that its showing me a the error as above asked question

Comment: If you're importing a different location from local pc then the command line you're using there won't work. See my edited answer if that would work for you.

Comment: I have code of wordpress site and DB  that i downloaded from different server and now i am trying to run that code using xampp server in local.   and i am following all steps  like  to run wordpress site 
I have created data base with the same name of DB  in local and imported it directly  but that shown some errors. after that i am trying to open site on local its  showing me error  " Error establishing a database connection"  so  here either the DB user name and password is wrong written in wp config file .. 
Or  i have doubt thats why i am  trying command

Comment: Wait, that seems to be a totally different problem then what you've posted. So, you actually want to create a local DB so you can run a wordpress-like site locally?

Comment: I have outsourced my project to developer but they were not doing it as i want . i asked them to send me code they sent  to me and now i am trying to run that code in local. I hope now its clear  and i am getting errors when trying  with xampp

Comment: DB installed  locally  but still getting error "Error establishing a database connection"

is it a case that they written wrong user name and password in wp.config file ?

Comment: It's possible and it's not limited to just username and/or password. The port could also be different than the mysql service that was installed. I think the first step for you is to figure out what was the credentials being set in the config file. Once you have that, you can configure your mysql service to match all those requirements. For example if config file have `user = user1` and `password = password1`, make sure your local db also have that credentials or if config file is using `port = 8000`, then you have to configure mysql's `my.ini` to use the same port.